# Application update notifier in Visual Studio App Center

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I am using visual studio app center to distribute my application the problem is I need my distribution groups to be notified when there is an update to my application and force them to update so that all of my distribution group will have the latest version. The code below I got it from the Microsoft website and I put it inside my **App.xaml.cs** under **OnStart()**. The problem is the notification for a new version of the is not displaying or notifying my distribution group.

```
protected override void OnStart ()
{
    AppCenter.Start("android=<appsecret>;", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes), typeof(Distribute));
    Analytics.SetEnabledAsync(true);

    Distribute.ReleaseAvailable = OnReleaseAvailable;

    bool OnReleaseAvailable(ReleaseDetails releaseDetails)
    {
        string versionName = releaseDetails.ShortVersion;
        string versionCodeOrBuildNumber = releaseDetails.Version;
        string releaseNotes = releaseDetails.ReleaseNotes;
        Uri releaseNotesUrl = releaseDetails.ReleaseNotesUrl;

        var title = "Version " + versionName + " available!";
        Task answer;

        if (releaseDetails.MandatoryUpdate)
        {
           answer = Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, releaseNotes, "Download and Install");
        }
        else
        {
           answer = Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, releaseNotes, "Download and Install", "Ask Later");
        }
        answer.ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
           if (releaseDetails.MandatoryUpdate || (task as Task<bool>).Result)
           {
               Distribute.NotifyUpdateAction(UpdateAction.Update);
           }
           else
           {
               Distribute.NotifyUpdateAction(UpdateAction.Postpone);
           }
       });

        return true;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If [this is the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin#xamarinforms) you followed, the only thing I see that it says to explicitly add to the OnStart() method is the `AppCenter.Start(...)` method call:

> Open your App.xaml.cs (or your class that inherits from Xamarin.Forms.Application) in your shared or portable project and add the method below in the OnStart() override method.

```
AppCenter.Start("ios={Your Xamarin iOS App Secret};android={Your Xamarin Android App secret}", typeof(Distribute));
```

Then later on, in [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/xamarin#2-customize-the-update-dialog), it talks about customizing the update dialog, where it says:

> You can customize the default update dialog's appearance by implementing the `ReleaseAvailable` callback. You need to register the callback **before** calling `AppCenter.Start` as shown in the following example:

```
Distribute.ReleaseAvailable = OnReleaseAvailable;
AppCenter.Start(...);
```

So, according to the above `Distribute.ReleaseAvailable = OnReleaseAvailable;` has to be called **before** `AppCenter.Start`. You are calling it after.

Also not sure if it is just a formatting error when you posted your question, but it looks like you are implementing the `OnReleaseAvailable` method inside the `OnStart()` method, which is not legal in C# (or not until C# 7 anyway, which I just realized... cool). So unless you're using C# 7, you will want to implement the `OnReleaseAvailable` method outside of the `OnStart()`, or any other, method. IOW it should be implemented as a direct member of the class. E.g.:

```
protected override void OnStart ()
{
    Distribute.ReleaseAvailable = OnReleaseAvailable;
    AppCenter.Start("android=<appsecret>;", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes), typeof(Distribute));
    Analytics.SetEnabledAsync(true);
}

bool OnReleaseAvailable(ReleaseDetails releaseDetails)
{
     ... 
}
```

Comment: Where do I put OnReleaseAvailable ?

Comment: At the same level as OnStart(); I will update answer.

Comment: What else do I need to do In order for this to work?

Comment: That should be it, as far as I can see. Go over the docs again and see if there is anything else you may have misunderstood.

Comment: How about the part in Customize or localize text that part I really dont understand the use of it

Comment: That would require teaching how to localize text for each platform. That "Customize or localize text" section is only directing you to what text the AppCenter library may display in your app, so you use the platform localization techniques to localize the strings in the linked string resource files.  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/ . Localization is a big and sometimes complex topic.

Comment: Do I need that or is that optional?

Comment: Only need it if you want the AppCenter Update dialog text to be translated to whatever language the device is set for.